# Went off the rails with a prime number Generator

Tags: list, function, iteration

I am doing a prime number generator for an assignment. I have been doing it most the day and am starting to think i got confused. It is intended to take an input and list all the numbers that are prime and less than the entry number. How do i get back on track to that?

code below:

```
print("Please enter a number other than 1, and if the number is prime, all prime numbers of lesser value will be listed:")
entryNum = int(input())
#Sets the number to entryNum
primeNums = []
if entryNum == 1:
    print("That number is beyond the confines of definition here.")
elif entryNum % 2 == 0:
    print("This number is not prime, it is composite. Most even numbers are composite.")
elif entryNum == 2:
    print("There are no primary numbers below 2. Some may argue that 1 is, but those individuals should really make a strong argument for it.")
else:

    counter = 2
    while counter < entryNum:
        if entryNum % counter == 0:
            primeNums.append(counter)
            counter+=1
        else:
            counter+=1 
#Prime number tester and adder

    print("The prime numbers less than", entryNum, "are:")

    print(''.join(str(primeNums)))
    print("fun")
```

Comment: You're building a list of the *factors* of `entryNum`, which may or may not be prime.  You shouldn't care whether `counter` divides `entryNum`, you need to find out whether there are any numbers that divide `counter` - which is going to require another loop to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for the help jasonharper. My head was really turned around by all the code. Still took me a few hours to untangle the confusion I coded myself into.

below is what if ended up with:

```
print("Please enter a number other than 1, and if the number is prime, all prime numbers of lesser value will be listed:")
entryNum = int(input())
#Sets the number to entryNum
primeNums = []
counter = 2

def isPrime(n):
    if n == 1:#Test to see if 1 was entered
        return False
    elif n % 2 == 0:#Test to see if its even
        return False
    for i in range(2,n):#Test to see if there are any factors
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    else:#Returns true, allowing a number to be confirmed as prime
        return True  

if isPrime(entryNum) is True:
    print("Def is prime, dude, fo sho. Bellow are all the other prime numbers of lesser value")
    while counter < entryNum:
        if isPrime(counter) is True:
            primeNums.append(counter)
            counter+=1
        else:
            counter+=1 
else:
    print("this number is not prime")

print(*primeNums, sep = ",")
```